# ScrollTop function to change with Screen Width

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

Hi can someone help with my script please. This piece of code works fine in javascript:

```
    $("a[href='#tabs-11']").click(function() {     
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 620 }, "slow");    
    return false;   
    });
```

but now I need to do a different scroll height when screen resizes using this script but not working:

```
    $("a[href='#tabs-11']").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 620 }, "slow");
    if (window.innerWidth < 700) { 
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 620 }, "slow");
        return false;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
$("a[href='#tabs-11']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (window.innerWidth < 700) {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 20 }, "slow");
      return false;
    } else {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 1600 }, "slow");
    }
  });
```

you can change 20 or 1600 to any needed value.

Comment: Thank you kind sir for your prompt response and sharing of knowledge. I dont get any errors now just that it doesnt seem to be scrolling to different height even though I changed the second function to scrollTop: 900 could it be the window.innerwidth ? tried window.width as well still no results it still uses the first functions scrollTop : 620?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener on resize with function which will update the state of window width. Otherwise, your code doesn't understand that you are resizing

Comment: Thank you sooo so much brother that works perfectly! Many blessings to you and your loved ones for being so kind and helpful!! Wonderful stuff!

Comment: @ZeeMan I'm glad my answer helped you!